# Nice inequality with exponents $a^{2b}+b^{2a}\leq a^{\Big(\frac{a(1-a)(\frac{1}{2}-a)}{4}\Big)^2}$

Tags: inequality, polynomials, exponentiation

Hi it's a little refinement to play with a hard inequality of Vasile Cirtoaje :

> > Let $a\geq b>0$ such that $a+b=1$ then we have :
> > $$a^{2b}+b^{2a}\leq  a^{\Big(\frac{a(1-a)(\frac{1}{2}-a)}{4}\Big)^2}=f(a)$$

It implies directly the inequality of Vasile Cirtoaje .

I have tried the substitution $a=\sinh^2(x)$

$$\sinh(x)^{4\cosh^2(x)}+\cosh(x)^{4\sinh^2(x)}\leq  \sinh(x)^{\Big(\frac{\cosh^2(x)\sinh^2(x)(\frac{1}{2}-\sinh^2(x))}{2}\Big)^2}$$

But I think it's nothing .

If we take one element  of the sum and make the difference with the RHS and finally use derivatives it becomes awful . So I think it's a wrong way .

I have tried obviously Bernoulli's inequality as :

$$a^{2(1-a)}\leq 1+(a^2-1)((1-a)) \quad, (1-a)^{2(a)}\leq 1+((1-a)^2-1)(a)$$

But I don't know what to do next maybe there exists a reversed Bernoulli's inequality (?).Now I'm stuck because it's a hard nut (it could be my song).

Thanks in advance for all your advices and others things!

### Little update

Maybe we can compare the upper bound got with Bernoulli's inequality with an inequality of the kind :
$$1+\Big(\frac{a(1-a)(\frac{1}{2}-a)}{4}\Big )^{\alpha}\leq a^{\Big(\frac{a(1-a)(\frac{1}{2}-a)}{4}\Big)^2}=f(a)$$

We can determine easily $\alpha$ numericaly .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality for $0\le b\le 1/2$, $a+b=1$, $$a^{2b}+b^{2a}\leq  a^{\Big(\frac{ab(b-a)}{8}\Big)^2}\tag{1}$$ can be strengthened to $$a^{2b}+b^{2a}\le e^{-3a^2b^2(b-a)^2/4}\tag{2}$$ noting that $e^{-3a^2b^2(b-a)^2/4}\le a^{\Big(\frac{ab(b-a)}{8}\Big)^2}$ unless $a$ is almost $0$.

Only a sketch proof is given here, for what it's worth.

For brevity, let $f(x):=x^{1-x}$ and  $g(x):=x^2(1-x)^2(x-\frac{1}{2})^2$. The claim is $$f(x)^2+f(1-x)^2\le e^{-3g(x)}$$

Trivially, $f(x)\ge x$, $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=1$, $f(1)=1$, $f'(1)=0$. $f'(x)=\frac{1-x-x\ln x}{x^x}$.

*Proposition 1.* $f'(x)=0\iff x=1$

Proof: $\frac{1}{x}-\ln x=1$, equivalent to $\frac{1}{x}+\ln\frac{1}{x}=1$, so $x=\frac{1}{W(e)}=1$. ($W$ is Lambert's function.)

*Proposition 2.* $f(x)^2+f(1-x)^2$ has three local maxima, at $x=0,\frac{1}{2},1$.

Proof:  The maxima/minima of $f(x)^2+f(1-x)^2$ occur when $f(x)f'(x)=f(1-x)f'(1-x)$.

At $x=0$, $f(0)=0=f'(1)$; at $x=1$, $f(1-x)=0=f'(1)$. Otherwise, divide by $f(x)$, $f(1-x)$.

At $x=0$, $$f(x)^2+f(1-x)^2=e^{2(1-x)\ln x}+e^{2x\ln(1-x)}=x^2+o(x)+1-2x^2+o(x)=1-x^2+o(x)$$ Hence $x=0$ is a local maximum. By symmetry, so is $x=1$.

The function $\frac{f'(x)}{f(1-x)} =  \frac{1-x-x \ln x}{(x(1-x))^x}$ lies between $1$ and $2$, and has one local maximum and one local minimum. A sketch is as follows (blue curve).

[image]

$\frac{f'(x)}{f(1-x)}=\frac{f'(1-x)}{f(x)}$ at three places; the intersections are simple. Since $x=0$ is a local maximum, it follows that the only other local maximum is at $x=1/2$. Then $f(1/2)=1$.

*Corollary* $F(x):=-\ln(f(x)^2+f(1-x)^2)$ also has three local minima at $x=0,\frac{1}{2},1$.

A Taylor expansion at each point gives $F(0+h)=h^2+o(h)$, $F(1/2+h)=ch^2+o(h)$ where $c=4 - 4\ln2 - 2\ln^22\approx0.267$, $F(1-h)=h^2+o(h)$.

Hence fitting a polynomial with double roots at $x=0,\frac{1}{2},1$, namely $\alpha g(x)$, a necessary condition for $\alpha g(x)\le F(x)$ is $\alpha\le \min(4,16c)=4$. A sketch of $F(x)$ shows that the worst cases are at these points; and that $\alpha\le3$ is sufficient for $F(x)\ge3g(x)$. No simple proof for this, just a splitting into ranges $[0,1/8]$, $[1/8,3/8]$, $[3/8,1/2]$, and use Taylor series on each.

[image]

*Proposition 3.* For $x>e^{-16\alpha}$, $$e^{-\alpha g(x)}\le x^{(g(x)/4)^2}$$

Proof: Follows from $-\alpha g(x)\le g(x)\ln x/16$, equivalent to $\ln x\ge-16\alpha$, or $x\ge e^{-16\alpha}$.

Comment: Thanks it's seems good to me but just for the proposition 3 you have a strict inequality wich becomes an equality .I think it's not a serious problem .(+1)

Comment: Well in fact it's very nice I accept !!